# How to change font size in JQPlot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using following code to built a simple line chart using jqplot.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line1 = [14, 32, 41, 44, 40, 47, 53, 67];
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
      title: 'Chart with Point Labels', 
      seriesDefaults: { 
        showMarker:false,
        pointLabels: { show:true } 
      }
  });
});
```

I want to change the font size of the label. Any ideas on how to do it??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After the chart renders you can detect the code behind it using dev tools like chrome dev tools or fire bug.

As long as the chart plugin creates standard markup and not svg or canvas, you can resolve a way to catch the labels through css using the proper css selector then apply the font and/or any other styling you need to the labels.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
axesDefaults: {
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                    tickOptions: {
                      angle: -30,
                      fontSize: '10pt'
                    }
               },
```